# Orientdb 3.0.0-M2, Live Query gives java.lang.NullPointerException [ONetworkProtocolBinary]

Tags: orientdb

I was trying to build some live queries on the Orient Db 3.0.0-M2.
But when I try to execute the query it gives an Null pointer exception. I enabled Fine log level in my Orient Server, and found the below line in the server.

```
Sent run-time exception to the client /192.168.1.102:63830: java.lang.NullPointerException [ONetworkProtocolBinary]
```

The Code I am using to query is:

```
int monitorId = db.live("LIVE SELECT FROM Mark", new MyOLiveQueryResultListener()).getMonitorId;
```

On the Java client I get the below exception (which I guess is the server side counterpart of the error- correct me if I am wrong).

```
   Exception in thread "Thread-5" com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OResponseProcessingException: Exception during response processing
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.throwSerializedException(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:339)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.handleStatus(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:280)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemotePushThread.run(OStorageRemotePushThread.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentEmbedded.copy(ODatabaseDocumentEmbedded.java:305)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.LiveQueryListenerImpl$1.call(LiveQueryListenerImpl.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.LiveQueryListenerImpl.execInSeparateDatabase(LiveQueryListenerImpl.java:202)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.LiveQueryListenerImpl.<init>(LiveQueryListenerImpl.java:65)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentEmbedded.live(ODatabaseDocumentEmbedded.java:501)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OConnectionBinaryExecutor.executeSubscribeLiveQuery(OConnectionBinaryExecutor.java:1310)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.message.OSubscribeLiveQueryRequest.execute(OSubscribeLiveQueryRequest.java:77)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OConnectionBinaryExecutor.executeSubscribe(OConnectionBinaryExecutor.java:1283)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.message.OSubscribeRequest.execute(OSubscribeRequest.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.sessionRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:274)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:180)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
```

I also Tried to do this with the way its shown in the documentation for Orient DB 2.2.x, But I get the same error, plus the call to db.query(OLiveQuery) is deprecated.

Comment: never mind, I was using the root username and password and that was creating some issue. Instead if I use admin username and password, it works the way expected.